# errors due to adding images in resource folder drawable-hdpi

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, user-interface

I want to develop the interface of my app in which i am supposed to add image buttons for (map, navigation, info, time measurement, search) and an option menu displaying two buttons ('about' & 'exit')...help me in making such a interface ... when i add the images in resource drawable-hdpi folder an error is displayed in java file stating "R can not be resolved into a variable"
    following is the code of java file

```
package com.example.margallahillshikedroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //error appears here"R can not be resolved into a variable"


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    return true;
}

}
```

logcat is as follows;

```
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon- small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png:  Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\layout\activity_main.xml:1: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\drawable-hdpi\button_img.xml:4: error: Error: No  resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_action_search').
[2014-03-29 07:59:56 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\drawable-hdpi\button_img.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_action_search').
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\layout\activity_main.xml:1: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\drawable-hdpi\button_img.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_action_search').
[2014-03-29 08:00:05 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\drawable-hdpi\button_img.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_action_search').
 [2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
 [2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
 [2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
 [2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\layout\activity_main.xml:1: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').
[2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\drawable-hdpi\button_img.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_action_search').
[2014-03-29 08:00:45 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\drawable-hdpi\button_img.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_action_search').
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\layout\activity_main.xml:1: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\drawable-hdpi\button_img.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_action_search').
[2014-03-29 08:01:29 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\drawable-hdpi\button_img.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_action_search').
[2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
 [2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
 [2014-03-29 08:03:41 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\layout\activity_main.xml:1: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').
[2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
 [2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:03:48 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\layout\activity_main.xml:1: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid   file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Inval id file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:18 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\layout\activity_main.xml:1: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:28 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\layout\activity_main.xml:1: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').
[2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
 [2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Google-Maps-app-icon-small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] res\drawable-hdpi\alarm-clock-icon_small.jpg: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[2014-03-29 08:04:35 - MargallaHillsHikedroid] E:\my android projects\MargallaHillsHikedroid\res\layout\activity_main.xml:1: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap content').
//please tell me how to develop the interface with all those buttons and option menu...if you see the menu of 'map factor' android app ....mine's app menu interface should look exactly alike....
```

Comment: Delete all capital letters, hyphens and spaces from the image names. For example, google_maps_app_icon_small.png

Comment: @Onik i still get the same error

Comment: Google-Maps-app-icon- small.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.  What don't you understand about the error message?  You can't have Uppercase and you can't have dashes.  Rename your file to:  googlemapsappicon or google_maps_app_icon.

Comment: @user3431536 There is also an error in activity_main.xml, post it. Also several drawables can't be found. Check if they're in the folders with the correct names.

Comment: @wyoskibum yeah i had been doing what you said but still getting the same error but now when i restarted my IDE it worked fine....

Comment: @Onik HOW TO MAKE the interface i mentioned about

Comment: @Onik JUST TELL me the procuedure

Comment: `\Search-icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]` Replace **-** with **_** in all your file names

Comment: @wyoskibum please help me out with the interface design ;(

Comment: Copy your files into a new folder then and remove them from your project.  Using the filemanager, make sure all of your files are lowercase without dashes and any spaces.  Once you are certain the files are correct, import them back into your project.  Do a clean and see if your R.java file is created.